# Need help coding an answer in R

Tags: r

[image: Reverse Rank Question in R]

I do not know how the X or Y vector relate to each other in this question. The fact that the answer is a single vector is what is confusing me the most.

I tried doing the negative rank (i.e. rank(-s)) and then trying

rev(rank(X)) and rev(rank(Y)) and I am getting incorrect rank returns. Here's my code:

```
x <- c(-1, 0, 1, 2, -3) #vector x
y <- c(1, 3, 2, 5, 8) # Vector y 
S <- x[order(match(x,y))] #orders and matches x with y 
R <- rank(-S) #ranks S in element number order 
print(R) #I want R = (5 2 1 3 4)
```

instead, I get `[2 1 4 3 5]`

with this other code:

```
never <- rev(rank(-x)) #takes the reverse rank of x 
bird <- rev(rank(y)) #takes the reverse rank of y
kid <- x[order(match(never, bird))] #orders the match of the reverse ranks
tr <- rank(kid) #ranks the match of the reverse ranks 
print(tr)
```

I get `[2 1 3 4 5]`.

Comment: Pr0P5 4 dE 0utr1Ght bRAzenNes5

Comment: Well, we know you're good at one thing.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question (which is not clear, I agree), there seems to be an error, but $x$ and $y$ are linked by the $s_i$ index.

Following the question: Let us find the $s_1$ index thanks to $y$. We know that $y_{s_1}$ is the largest value of $y$, hence $y_5$ in this case. Thus, $s_1 = 5$, so we need to find the reverse rank of $x_5 = -3$. As this is the lowest value, we have $r_1 = 5$.

Now with this approach, we would have $s_2 = 4$, so my guess is that there is an error in the example or the question.

In the example, I happen to have $R = (5, 1, 3, 2, 4)$.

You can notice that if you sort $y$, then apply the sorting rule to $x$ to create $x'$, the $R$ vector is the sorting rule of $x'$.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
x <- c(-1,0,1,2,-3)
y <- c(1,3,2,5,8)

myrank <- function(x,y)
{
  R=c()
     {
       for(i in 1:length(x))
          {
             b=length(y)+1-rank(y)
             a=length(y)+1-rank(x[b]) # here x[b] is to order the x values according to b
             R=c(a)
          }
     }
  print(R)
}
myrank(x,y)
```